# Is there 'false flag' war crime in ATLA?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, politics, crime

### Scenario (in ATLA) :

Hypothetically, if the concept of 'false flag' war crimes exists in ATLA, then based on S01E17, Sokka is ostensibly a war criminal. See the reddit discussions on [Iroh's war criminal status](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheLastAirbender/comments/py2u9h/irhos_not_a_war_criminal_for_being_a_general/) and [Sokka's potential status](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheLastAirbender/comments/qr9uv0/friendly_reminder_that_sokka_is_a_war_criminal/).

### Context (from our world) :

The International Committee of the Red Cross defines the [Practice Relating to Rule 62. Improper Use of Flags or Military Emblems, Insignia or Uniforms of the Adversary](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/customary-ihl/eng/docs/v2_cou_nz_rule62):

> According to custom, it is permissible for a belligerent warship to use false colours and to disguise her outward appearance in other ways in order to deceive an enemy, provided that prior to going into action the warship shows her true colours. Aircraft are not, however, entitled to use false markings.

From [false flag Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag#cite_ref-9)

> In land warfare, such operations are generally deemed acceptable under certain circumstances, such as to deceive enemies, provided the deception is not perfidious and that all such deceptions are discarded before opening fire upon the enemy. Similarly, in naval warfare such a deception is considered permissible, provided the false flag is lowered and the true flag raised before engaging in battle.

### Question:

Assuming such rules would also exist in Avatar, why didn't Sokka, say, prepare Water/Earth/Air Nation flags and then raise them before counter-attacking the Fire Nation during the Battle for the Northern Air Temple? I forgot the episode...was it infeasible given the impending nature of the particular attack or something? Or do such rules not exist?

Or... was there actually no need to do so even following similar laws (if they exist) i.e. **Sokka somehow isn't a war criminal even under similar laws**?

Comment: I don’t think this question is a good fit. Even real world war crimes questions are complicated and in some ways the victors of a war and the courts they influence decide what is a war crime. For all we know, this fictional world doesn’t even have a concept of war crimes and I can’t see how it adds to the understanding, analysis, or enjoyment of this world to discuss this extreme hypothetical with no hope of a clear objective answer.

Comment: @ToddWilcox given that Iroh has a sort of redemption arc based on his involvement in the war, I don't see how questions about war crimes in the fiction aren't a good fit?

Comment: Based on the extensive edits and efforts to draw people into conversation, it certainly suggests that you're wanting to have a *discussion* about this, not ask a single objectively answerable question

Comment: The answer given below is exactly what I want. What I'm trying to do is rephrase this correctly like praying vs smoking and smoking vs praying. I'm not interested in discussion because the answer given below is done for me. I think I can phrase this better once I understand the [intent of the false flag law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83487/whats-the-intent-of-the-false-flag-law), in which case I can speak stage 3 not stage 2 morality.

Comment: I've rolled this back to the version of the question as it existed at the time the answer was given (except for minor changes). You cannot substantially change a question once you have received answer(s), since that would invalidate the answer(s). Instead, ask a new question if you need to.

Comment: @Null LOL are you the mod from the other sub too? Again, all I have to say is 'edit to address comments and new answer'. It's exactly the case if someone in maths se for example has forgotten to add an assumption of 'independence' in random variables. Ask maths se if they agree with you. Scifi se can have its own rules, but don't go around talking as if it's universal on SE

Comment: I've rolled back the question again and locked it since you rolled back my edit. The lock is temporary, but I'm following this post so any attempt to roll back my edit after the lock is removed will result in a permanent lock. When the temporary lock is removed you will be free to make minor edits *so long as in doing so you do not invalidate the existing answer*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find this question slightly confusing, since it seems as if it is basically asking why rules designed in one social context are not applied in another, completely different context where they may not even exist. However, I will try to answer it.

There are a few important points here:

1. First and perhaps most important, the laws mentioned in the question exist in the *real world*. Sokka is all but a child in a completely different world from planet Earth, with technological and social traits that seem to roughly correspond to Asia and particularly China hundreds of years in the past, with many social differences from any place on Earth at any time in history. Why should we expect such customs or laws to exist in that world at all? Even if they do, why should we expect Sokka to know or care about them? As a reminder, he is a 15-year-old child (or young man) from a tribe in a fictional world, *not* an adult legal scholar on Earth.
2. More than that, though, such laws are not even respected everywhere in the real world. The [linked page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag#cite_ref-9) notes that prohibitions on using false emblems to gain the advantage of surprise against enemies are in fact only law at the national level, and as such may vary from nation to nation, and that in many cases are merely customary. Apparently there have been drafts in this regard, but they have not been ratified. Even if we assume that someone—the Southern Water Tribe, say—has developed laws around deception in warfare that exactly parallel those on Earth in the present day, there is really no reason to assume that laws like those mentioned in the question have to exist. As mentioned before, if they do, there is no reason for Sokka to necessarily know about them.
3. More than *that*, though, the militaries that do have such rules actually often *permit* using the flag of the enemy for sneak attacks, as long as such flags are discarded before actually attacking, as mentioned in the linked article. That has been the position of the US military at times, for instance. Note that this last action need *not* actually give the attacked party any time to respond. A balloon with a flag on it *cannot* be discarded. So again, even if Sokka were following some modern Earth military's rules, he would have an argument that his attack was within the spirit of the rules, if not the letter.
4. Moving on from arguments that require Sokka to be an expert in real-life military law, the balloon had already been mostly constructed with a Fire Nation emblem on it, and there was an unknown but short time remaining before the Fire Nation attacked. Wasting time trying to paint the balloon instead of getting it in working condition would have been foolhardy in the extreme, and might have gotten many people killed.
5. One should also remember that the Fire Nation is a genocidal, expansionist empire that Sokka has many reasons to hate, and Aang and his friends are basically guerrillas. In guerrilla warfare in the real world—and, one presumes, in the *Avatar* universe—guerrillas often disregard some of the niceties of war when fighting their much more powerful opponents. In fact, what Aang and his friends get up to is quite mild in comparison. In short, if Aang and friends had obeyed every rule of war that exists in the real world or in their world, they would probably be dead, and even if that were not the case, there is no reason to believe that they are overly concerned about being punctilious about any warrior's code when it comes to the Fire Nation.
6. To cap it all off, dialogue suggests that Sokka and the rest were actually *surprised* that the Fire Nation was not shooting at them, suggesting that they were not even trying to take advantage of the emblem for a surprise attack in the first place:

> Sokka: Hey, why aren't they shooting at us?
>
> Mechanist: The insignia! They think we're on their side.
>
> <sub>"The Northern Air Temple"</sub>

Needless to say, after realizing this, they were not about to politely turn around and paint some identifying emblem on the balloon to give the Fire Nation fair warning, thus exposing themselves to attack and endangering their allies' lives.

Comment: Thanks Adamant. This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for: a precise version that already confirms everyone's intuition that Sokka isn't a war criminal largely because Sokka didn't have any bad intentions or anything and because of the impending nature of the attack as you point out in (4).

Comment: Wait what about that thing you said in the other post like 1 of the reasons of the false flag law is about trying to shift blame or something? Is that indeed relevant? Ah here it is: 'The intent of a false flag attack, as shown in your link, is to place the blame for an attack on someone else. Is that the case here?'

Comment: btw you can answer here if you want i'll just delete my (copy of your) answer https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83486/did-sokka-commit-the-war-crime-of-false-flag-atla-s01e17

Comment: Adding to your first few points, in 18th-19th century Europe, where most of our modern "customs of war" have their origin, they were enforced by diplomatic convention. A nation that was seen sheltering war criminals would lose face on the world stage. But in the *Avatar* universe, there is no "world stage". There are only three major polities, one of which is already at war with the other two! There would be little point in any nation writing up rules of war except for their own personal use, because there's no mechanism to enforce it on another nation.

Comment: @Cadence Consider answering here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267014/what-are-likely-to-not-be-considered-war-crimes-in-atla-tlok  or there https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/234792/what-are-likely-to-not-be-considered-war-crimes-in-a-universe-where-people-can-c