# What are likely to not be considered war crimes in ATLA (/TLOK)?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra, politics, crime

I believe it goes without saying that in any universe, we can expect that in war, bombing or taking orphanages or hospitals hostage, is a war crime, or in the absence of formalised international law, would be immoral/unethical as part of winning a war, regardless of whichever side you're on. And maybe even [false flag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266987/does-the-world-of-avatar-have-the-concept-of-false-flag-war-crimes) (or see [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83486/did-sokka-commit-the-war-crime-of-false-flag-atla-s01e17)).

However, I don't think we'd be surprised if we could find some international law from the Geneva's convention, International Committee of the Red Cross or United Nations whatever that is highly *specific to our* world that wouldn't apply **(by which I mean really 'necessarily would not apply' as opposed to 'would not necessarily apply' because of course everything 'would not necessarily apply'**) certainly in fictional universes (or even real worlds like some other planet in a remote galaxy or whatever).

**Question:** What might some such laws be?

For example, (I'll post as answer...)

Comment: This feels very subjective, since it's a completely different world and I'm not certain if "war crimes" came up during the show, or would even make sense in the time period given our world didn't really have any examples until [1474](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_crime#Early_examples).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots 1 - what about the linked post? 2 - of course war crimes came up in a show about a war. see the linked post. also genocide - killing innocent air nomads war crime? inhuman treatment war crime? jet and hama - war criminals? but anyway those are not necessarily bending specific.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that none of the actions in *Avatar: the Last Airbender* would be considered [war crimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_crime) because there is no evidence that such a framework of agreements exists, with the closest being the [RPG book](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Avatar_Legends:_The_Roleplaying_Game) establishing that Fire Lord Zuko, after the war, decided to criminalize past atrocities and to punish those involved. And even there, there's not much insight as to what exactly is being considered a war crime. Much like in our world, the rulings would likely vary from measures considered to be too cruel to measures considered too efficient, and individual powerful nations are likely to establish their own crimes based on their social mores.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the RPG. It is possible that it expands on what Zuko actually prosecuted as war crimes, which would allow us to determine what actions were not considered war crimes (at least by him) that would be by our standards.

Comment: Some possible food for thought at https://ultraericthered.tumblr.com/post/615878596454645760/uncle-iroh-wasnt-ever-a-war-criminal-there and https://zuko-always-lies.tumblr.com/post/662374153372991488/unambiguous-war-crimes-that-allies-of-the-gaang

Comment: I don't necessarily agree or disagree but the whole point of this question is hypothetical. Not just about applying our world's laws to their world but also about that they don't quite have a geneva's convention or anything from our world. please see my 2 posted answers to have an idea of what i mean and then perhaps you can tell me how i might clarify my question.

Answer (score -4):

## Answer 2:

Oh I got another one:

[image]

In S01E07, the earth kingdom soldiers are about to crush Iroh's hands. Of course crushing a prisoner's hands for no reason is prisoner abuse, but clearly this is self-defense to stop Iroh from bending since the ATLA/TLOK universe doesn't exactly have readily made anti-bending bracelets that you can put on benders to stop them from bending similar to those anti-magic bracelets in [OUAT](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113565/why-didnt-this-ouat-character-cut-off-their-hand-in-hopes-of-regrowing-it).

It should of course be noted that the they tried to imprison Iroh without doing this, but this proved impractical.

Answer (score -5):

## Answer 1:

For example, something specific in our world is that people can't firebend.

Consider this reddit [semi-meme post 'Everyone’s favourite war criminal' by user miscellaneous-nerd](https://www.reddit.com/r/ATLA/comments/fbnym9/everyones_favourite_war_criminal/) that says firebending would be considered an incendiary weapon and thus firebending against enemy soldiers in a civilian populace would be a violation of the UN '[Convention on Certain Conventional Weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_on_Certain_Conventional_Weapons#Protocol_III:_Incendiary_Weapons)':

[image]

You might apply this kind of rule to, say, the Harry Potter universe, where both sides can cast fire spells (Incendio?), but it's nonsensical to apply this to ATLA where firebending soldiers would fight with an inherent huge disadvantage. But I guess it might make sense to have a rule like firebenders should not, say, use a certain form of firebending instead of saying outright that all firebending in war is a war crime.

I can imagine that the other 3 elements might get UN / geneva exceptions too. Haven't thought of anything specific yet though.

Conversely, while bending the 3 other elements might not be war crimes in our world (if people in our world somehow become benders), I can imagine some forms of bending might actually be war crimes. But again, I haven't thought of anything specific yet though.

Comment: In the future please don't delete an answer only to post a pretty much identical one with a bit of stuff tacked on the end.